# How implement mouse on Android TV boxes on platform rockchip?

Tags: android, mouse, remote-control

I have an "MINIX NEO X7 mini" Android device. There is installed application eHomeMediaCenter. It is a DLNA server. Then I launch RKRemoteControl application on my Android smartphone, select eHomeMediaCenter and see mouse cursor on my Minix. And then I can move and click. But what protocol is used for that? And why in eHomeMediaCenter? Please, give me some info about that.

Answer (score 1):

Mouse and keyboard functions in the Minix Neo -- and probably Android devices in general -- builds on the desktop Linux keyboard and mouse support, specifically on /dev/hidraw -- the Human Input Drivers.  See [enter link description here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/hid/hidraw.txt) for more info.  A variety of external mice, keyboards or 'air mouse/keyboards' can be connected to the Minix Neo x5/x7 by USB, Bluetooth or other wired or wireless connection and feed mouse events of keyboard events to the normal Linux HID processing that Java -- and the Android apps consume.

I use [this air mouse/keyboard](http://www.minix.com.hk/Products/MINIX-NEO-A2.html) with the Neo x5. (Air mouse means that the device is not placed on a desk, but accelerometers in the device allow you to wave the thing around to produce mouse movement.)  What ever (perhaps proprietary) protocol is used between the device and the device driver is converted (in the device driver) to a data stream that emulates the signals that a conventional, old style, wired mouse or keyboard produced.  Some devices use a generic HID device driver that is used for a serial (ie old RS-232, TTY, phone modem) device.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. I made some research work and found that software mouse is controled by appliaction eHomeMediaCenter. Information about events are sended from control device via UDP socket port 56456. Now I try to understand what is that 21 bytes that are sended.

Comment: @MichalHainc , sorry, I don't know. Can you try with other ports and applications? I mean some test app "sender" which will send udp package on port 57000 and some test app "receiver" that will receive this udp package. Try it to know exactly that there are no network issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
go through below link
```

http://support.aboway.com.tw/products/android/A18/TV%20stick%20mobile%20remote/RKRemoteControlGeneralCastV2.0.3/doc/index.html?com/rockchip/remotecontrol/common/DeviceCache.DeviceChangeListener.html
u will get code to implement